# Erro Open.CV salvar arquivo

Tags: c#, opencv

Bom dia pessoal, possuo o seguinte código:

```
var faceImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(new Bitmap(bm));
                imagensFace[i] = faceImage.Resize(100, 100, Inter.Cubic);
                faceLabels[i] = todasFaces[i].ID;
            }
            faceRecognizer.Train(imagensFace, faceLabels);
            faceRecognizer.Save("C:/Temp");
```

porem ao passar na parte que salva o faceRecognizer é apontado o seguinte erro: Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: File can't be opened for writing!'

Abaixo esta a declaração do faceRecognizer:

```
FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(80, double.PositiveInfinity);
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser que a biblioteca consiga interpretar a `/` no caminho do arquivo, mas o normal é `\`.

Você pode tentar:

```
faceRecognizer.Save("C:\\Temp");
```

ou

```
faceRecognizer.Save("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Emgu\\Teste.yml");
```

outra situação (mais provável) é que, como está salvando em C:, o sistema operacional pede elevação de privilégios, você pode resolver isso mudando o local onde vai salvar o arquivo, colocando em documentos, imagens, área de trabalho... ou elevar a execução do visual studio, o famoso `Executar como administrador`

Comment: Estou salvando em "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Emgu" mas o erro persiste, tentei executar como administrador e também não resolveu :/

Comment: o mesmo erro ? por acaso, você abre o arquivo pra leitura em outro trecho do código ? se sim, poste o trecho também. @Brayan

Comment: Na verdade não abro ele em lugar algum, pois preciso fazer ele ser salvo antes para que mais pra frente eu abra ele

Comment: alterei a resposta, tente fazer da segunda forma, e caso dê erro, coloque o stacktrace aqui @Brayan

Comment: Rovan consegui, na verdade faltava por o nome da extensão do arquivo por exemplo "C:\\Temp\\Teste.xml" mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela atenção :D

Comment: Ops não vi, é exatamente a resposta que você alterou, só que com extensão .xml